# Enable smooth keyboard scrolling but disable smooth mouse scrolling in Firefox

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, scrolling, mouse-wheel

I want the same smooth scrolling behavior as current Chrome/Edge(mium) versions: snappy touchpad scrolling without delay, but smooth and slower scrolling when using the arrow keys on the keyboard.

Right now, in Firefox 73.0, I can either:

- Enable all smooth scrolling, which makes arrow-key scrolling pleasant, but touchpad scrolling annoyingly slow and unnatural.
- Disable all smooth scrolling, which lets me lets me "grab" the page intuitively with the touchpad, but leads to instant discontinuous jumps when arrow-key scrolling, making text harder to follow.

How can I enable smooth scrolling only for keyboard controls?

Answer (score 0):

Found it just after asking: at the `about:config` URL, setting the `general.smoothScroll.mouseWheel` setting to `false` will prevent touchpad scrolling from being smoothed, while keyboard scrolling will still be affected by the "Enable smooth scrolling" option in `about:preferences`.

The downside is that scrolling with a typical mouse wheel will still lead to discontinuous jumps, so this isn't a perfect solution.